# PowerShell script to check if autoscale is enabled in Azure Cosmos

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I am writing a powershell script that checks if autoscale is enabled in cosmosdb and if it isn't then it should enable autoscaling. I am not able to find a powershell script or command that lets us check if autoscaling is enabled or not. I am referring the following document which only has a command to enable autoscaling.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/scripts/powershell/sql/throughput?toc=%2Fpowershell%2Fmodule%2Ftoc.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the autoscaling is enabled or not on a container by inspecting `AutoscaleSettings` of the `$througput` object returned by the Cmdlet. If a container has the throughput set as `Manual`, then `MaxThrougput` property of the auto scale settings would return zero.

```
$account = "account-name"
$resourceGroup = "resource-group-name"
$database = "database-name"
$container = "container-name"

$throughput = Get-AzCosmosDBSqlContainerThroughput -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
    -AccountName $account -DatabaseName $database -Name $container

$autoscaleSettings = $throughput.AutoscaleSettings

if ($autoscaleSettings.MaxThroughput -eq 0) {
  Write-Host "Autoscaling is not set on the container"
} else {
  Write-Host "Autoscaling is set on the container"
}
```